# JWT и OAuth для нескольких устройств

Tags: oauth, jwt

Как работает JWT и OAuth по отдельности я приблизительно представляю. Но как их совместить и при этом оставить возможность работы с несколькими устройствами? Я вижу это так

1. Клиент генерирует идентификатор для устройства. **DeviceId**
2. Передает **DeviceId**, **Login**, **Password** на сервер
3. Сервер генерирует **AccessToken**, **RefreshToken** и сохраняет последний в связке с **DeviceId** чтоб разграничить сессии на разных устройствах.

Тут то и вопросы:

1. Что касательно компрометации токена на одном из устройств? При использовании **RefreshToken** атакующий разлогинит пользователя только на этом устройстве, как быть с остальными
2. Как инвалидировать **AccessToken** прежде времени? Допустим если у пользователя поменялась роль, или если пользователь хочет разлогиниться на всех устройствах

Как это вообще делается по уму, у кого есть опыт реализации?

Answer (score 1):

Если клиент может работать с нескольких устройств (бизнес-регламент это позволяет), то специально ничего делать не нужно.

В идеале у вас REST-сервис, то есть сервис, которые не хранит пользовательские состояния. Клиентское приложение хранит всю информацию, необходимую для отправки запросов, и, значит, несколько клиентских приложений могут работать одновременно, не мешая друг другу. Это одно из преимуществ использования REST.

Если же клиент не должен работать с нескольких устройств (явно запрещено регламентом), то на сервере после проверки пароля достаточно удалять из кеша старые access token и refresh token. Это приведёт к тому, что все остальные клиентские приложения будут разлогинены и перейдут в состояние "нужно ввести логин и пароль". На самом деле таких приложений не может быть больше одного. В таком сценарии `DeviceId` не нужен.

Он может потребоваться, если вы хотите перед разлогином послать уведомление на устройство о том, что произошло. Но тут всё зависит от вашей библиотеки для отправки уведомлений, скажем, в SignalR вы отправляете сообщение пользователю по его идентификатору, а не устройству по идентификатору устройства.

В общем случае `DeviceId` наверное не нужен совсем.

Теперь по вопросам:

1. *Как компрометировать токен?* Как определено вашими заказчиками. Если речь идёт о бане в смысле отключения пользователя за нарушения, то чистить надо все пары токенов для данного пользователя.
2. *Как инвалидировать access token?* Чтобы инвалидировать access token раньше времени придётся использовать кэш, на который я тут всё время ссылался. Мы складываем в Redis пары access token и refresh token на время жизни рефреш токена. Значения из кеша удаляются при отключении (бане), при логауте, при перелогине (если надо чтобы только с одно устройства можно было подключиться).

Comment: 1. В плане токен увел хакер)
2. Тогда теряется вся суть JWT, и привичные сессии заменяются кэшем

Comment: 1. С технической точки зрения надо чистить в кэше либо одну пару токенов, либо все. 2. Без кэша вы не сможете реализовать отзыв JWT, поэтом, возможно, вы не совсем уловили, что такое *суть JWT*. Можете держать их в базе, но в Redis удобнее.

Comment: Если все равно прийдется обращаться к кэшу, тогда токен может быть и без **payload** и **signature**, а это уже не JWT. К примеру `'access_token' = "{$expireDttm}.{$randomHash}"` он и будет ключем в redis, а значение это и будет payload. Тогда отзыв токена, будет ничто иное как очистка кэша. За временем жизни, будет следить сам кэш, а передавать его на клиент, только чтоб слиент сам понимал сколько токену осталось

Comment: @Ninazu Вы можете не хранить в кэше целый токен, а только его идентификатор для проверки, тогда payload и signature вам потребуются. В целом вы правы -- многие стандарты не очень хорошо продуманы, в том числе и JWT. Без кэша нет возможности отозвать токен. Если придумаете способ, как это сделать, напишите, думаю, все серверные программисты будут его с удовольствием применять.